# setBackground function moves the JDialog/Jframe from the center in Java9

Tags: java, jframe, java-9, jdialog

I am using following code to display a splash screen. Following works great in Java 8. But in Java 9, I observed the splash screen is not in the center anymore but towards the top left side.

```
dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setModal(false);
dialog.setUndecorated(true);
dialog.getRootPane().setOpaque(false);
dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
dialog.setResizable(false);
...
dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

I confirmed that the issue happening from

> ```
> dialog.setBackground
> ```

But don't know why. I tried it with JFrame and had the same issue. Any idea how to fix it in Java 9?

Edited:

Following is the complete code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class SplashScreen
{

    private static JDialog  dialog;
    private String          fImage;

    static JProgressBar     progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    public SplashScreen(String image)
    {
        fImage = image;

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // hideSplashScreen
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void hideSplashScreen()
    {
        dialog.setVisible(false);
        dialog.dispose();
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // showSplashScreen
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void showSplashScreen() throws MalformedURLException
    {

        dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setModal(false);
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        dialog.getRootPane().setOpaque(false);
        dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        dialog.setResizable(false);

        // Scaling down
        Image image = new ImageIcon("C:\\SplashScreen.gif").getImage().getScaledInstance(700, 700, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dialog.add(background);

        dialog.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setForeground(new Color(0, 146, 189));

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // readVersion
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private String readVersion()
    {
        String version = "";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try
        {
            InputStream in = SplashScreen.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sciome/workbench/resources/version.properties");
            prop.load(in);
            in.close();
            version = prop.getProperty("version");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return version;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // setProgBarVisible
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setProgBarVisible(boolean bVisible)
    {
        progressBar.setVisible(bVisible);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // updateProgBar
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void updateProgBar(String strDetails, int nProgress)
    {
        progressBar.setValue(nProgress);
        progressBar.setString(strDetails + " (" + nProgress + "% complete).");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            showSplashScreen();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using jdk-9.0.1. Please make sure when you test the above code, you change the classpath to jdk-9.0.1 as well as the compilation and building setting to Java 9

Comment: On what OS is this occurring?  I cannot reproduce it in Linux.

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Are you executing your code in the AWT event dispatch thread?

Comment: yes. Thats true.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this in Windows 10.  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  Meaning, a complete program.

Comment: yes, I made an example for you and it worked fine. Not sure why i doesnt work with my application. I will get back to you if find anything

Comment: I had the classpath set to java 8 with my example and thats why it worked fine. I changed it to java 9 and can see the issue now. I have edited my question with the proper example.

Comment: All Swing and AWT methods must execute in the AWT event dispatch thread.  Failure to do so results in unpredictable behavior.  Place the body of your `main` method in a Runnable’s `run` method, and pass that Runnable to [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-).  For details, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.

Comment: I tired to run it in a Runnable's run method and passed it to EventQueue.invokeLater, still have the same issue.

Comment: I’m still not able to reproduce it on Windows 10, using Java 9.0.4.

Comment: I can confirm the issue as its happening also in my colleagues laptop and with setbackground option. please make sure you are not using java 8 in build path, compile and other places.